# JPA enity has three times this same relation

Tags: java, jpa, jpa-2.0, jpql

I have two simple models:

```
public class Wallet{
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    @Column(name = "WALLET_ID")
    private long walletId;

    @Column(name = "OWNER_LABEL")
    private String ownerLabel;

    @Column(name = "USER_ID")
    private long userId;
}
```

and

```
public class Transfer{

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    @Column(name = "TRANSFER_ID")
    private long transferId;

    @NotNull
    @Column(name = "AMOUNT")
    private BigDecimal amount = BigDecimal.ZERO;

    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name = "OWNER_WALLET_ID")
    private Wallet ownerWallet;

    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name = "FROM_WALLET_ID")
    private Wallet fromWallet;

    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name = "TO_WALLET_ID")
    private Wallet toWallet;
}
```

the problem is when I want to get transfer with all his relations (wallets) in one query

```
SELECT t FROM Transfer t 
LEFT JOIN FETCH t.ownerWallet w 
LEFT JOIN FETCH t.toWallet tw 
LEFT JOIN FETCH t.fromWallet fw 
WHERE w.userId = :userId ORDER BY t.createdAt DESC
```

I get the exception **MySQLIntegrityConstraintViolationException**: Duplicate entry '2' for key 'PRIMARY'
Do you have some soultion? Thanks in advise

Comment: Probably unrelated to the problem, but shouldn't you use `inner join` for `t.ownerWallet` since you search by `w.userId`?

Comment: A query doesn't throw an exception related to inserting data. If showing an exception give the stack trace and the persistence code it came from

Answer (score 0):

I'm pretty sure you are getting this error when trying to insert some data and have primary key duplicate. MySQLIntegrityConstraintViolationException is about constraint violation in DB model, nothing about selecting data.

Comment: I agree, but that should be a comment.